# Search text for matching strings to print line AND matching string

Tags: regex, string, awk, sed, grep

I am using awk to search a large text for matching strings.  My goal is to print the matching string, line number, and matching line.  I haven't been able to achieve the first part (ie. printing the matching string).

Currently I have:

```
awk '/string1/string2/string3/{ print NR, $0 }' file_to_search.txt
```

This produces the line number and matching line, but not the matching string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `/string1/string2/string3/` is not a valid regex. Are you searching test for `string1` OR `string2` OR `string3` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isnt clear but it sounds like this might be what you want:

```
awk 'match($0,/regexp/){ print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), NR, $0 }' file_to_search.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep, you can get the line number and the matching string or the complete line (as I know )

```
grep -wnoF "string1
string2
string3" infile
```

With awk, you can get what you look for

```
awk '
function findmatch(s,  i) {
 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {if ($i == s)
   {print "find string = "s,"on line number = "FNR,"Complete line = "$0}};
}
s1{findmatch(s1)}
s2{findmatch(s2)}
s3{findmatch(s3)}
' s1='string1' s2='string2' s3='string3' infile
```

Comment: Your `grep` _command_, as written, does not produce the desired output, i.e. **matching string**, **line number**, and **matching line**, only **line number** and **matching string**, which isn't even the right order.

Comment: You're obviously missing the point, which is why post a solution that doesn't in any way provide the requested output! The `grep` portion of your answer shouldn't be there. Also, IMO Your `awk` command is needlessly verbose and more complex then need be to get the expressed desired results. The other answer is more simplistic and can produce exactly what was asked for. Although to match the OP it will need to be used as `awk 'match($0,/regexp|regexp|regexp/){ print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), NR, $0 }' file_to_search.txt`, but it works and produces the stated desired output.

Comment: Yes, you are right for grep. With awk, try with nostring11 on a line and another line with string1 and string2 and come back.